# Where is P3-575 located?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

Along with P3-577, P3-575 was one of the first known locations to be visited by SGC designation in *Stargate SG-1*. What galaxy is P3-575 located in and what is its sitrep?

Comment: Hi @Habatchii, welcome to **Movies & TV**. Please indicate any research you've done to answer this question. Some research effort on the part of the questioner is encouraged prior to posting a query. Thanks!

Comment: Until they get a ZPM or build the fancy bridge, only gates in the Milky Way can be connected to.

Answer (score 2):

> What galaxy is P3-575 located in?

Well, P3-575 is a planet located in the Milky Way galaxy.

However, I couldn't find its siterep anywhere on the internet.

[source](http://en.stargatewiki.noip.me/index.php/P3-575)

Comment: I checked here: http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Prakiti